# Tricks to figure out how to login to Dexcom's API to get blood sugars?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Any way to figure out tricks to login to an API by Dexcom? [This article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BridgingDexcomShareCGMReceiversAndNightscout.aspx) discusses an approach for accessing blood sugar values but the first step is to log into the API and it is unclear how that step was taken as this is an undocumented API.

We are trying to help a diabetic get access to her blood sugar values so she can code new insulin dosing algorithms. (She wants to prevent the crashes and spikes in her blood sugars that ruin her days and put her at risk for blindness and being on dialysis. She believes and hopes human + machine can do better than her alone.)

If we are able to login the next steps for retrieving the values seem clear:

```
curl -k -X POST "https://share1.dexcom.com/ShareWebServices/Services/Publisher/ReadPublisherLatestGlucoseValues?sessionID=GUID&minutes=1440&maxCount=1" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Length: 0"
```

Is there anything to try that could give us a clue as to how take the first step and login to this API?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Dexcom clarity website
2. In your browser (let's assume Chrome for now) open the developer tools and go to the "Network" tab
3. Select the "data" XHR call. This is the "hidden API call" that populates the graphs in the Dexcom Clarity.
4. Right click and select "Copy > Copy as CURL (bash)". That will give you the CURL code that authenticates and logs into the website.
5. (Optional) Take the CURL command and paste it to https://curl.trillworks.com/ to translate the CURL code into some
   other language

`curl 'https://clarity.dexcom.com/api/subject/1522320180078ZZZZZZ/analysis_session/1560634749054XXXXXXX/data' -H 'Origin: https://clarity.dexcom.com' 
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' 
-H ..... -H 'Referer: https://clarity.dexcom.com/' -H --data-binary '{"localDateTimeInterval":["2016-05-01/2016-07-29"]}' --compressed`

Notice that you can change the data range by changing the values passed at `localDateTimeInterval` and get access to the full data in the account at a resolution of 5-min measurements. The returned JSON also includes all other events, such as calibrations, etc.